# Transmited Android Device as iBeacon but not showing in iPhone or iPad

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

My device turns into ibeacon it shows as iBeacon in AltBeacon Locate App as iBeacon but it is not detecting in iPhone and iPad and Mac.
Device :- Motorola Moto G XT1033

```
    BeaconTransmitter mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(
                this,
                new BeaconParser()
                        .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
                .setId2("1")
                .setId3("2")
                .setManufacturer(0x0000)
                // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot
                // detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] { 0l })).build();
        mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that the manufacturer code field is a company-specific identifier assigned by Bluetooth Sig.   You can see a full list of codes here:

https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers

When using proprietary beacon formats, you generally want to set the company code to the company that sponsors the beacon format.